# Nested LazyRow not scrolling vertically when scrolling LazyColumn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

For some reason, my `LazyRow` inside a `Cloumn` won't budge whenever I veritically scroll through the `LazyColumn`. The `LazyColumn` works perfectly though.

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    ReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "Demo",
        scaffoldContent = {
            MyScreenContent(contentPadding = it)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldFab: @Composable () -> Unit,
                       scaffoldContent: @Composable (contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = {Text(text = scaffoldTitle)},
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        content = { contentPadding -> scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding) }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    // Example data sets
    val rowItems = arrayOf(
        RowItems.ItemRowCheetah,
        RowItems.ItemRowPuma,
        RowItems.ItemRowJaguar,
        RowItems.ItemRowPanther,
        RowItems.ItemRowTiger
    )

    val columnItems = arrayOf(
        ColumnItems.ItemPetitFour,
        ColumnItems.ItemCupcake,
        ColumnItems.ItemDonut,
        ColumnItems.ItemEclair,
        ColumnItems.ItemFroyo
    )

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(contentPadding)) {
        Column(content = {
                ReusableLazyRow(
                    lazyRowItems = rowItems,
                    lazyRowItemLayout = {
                        Card(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(250.dp)
                                .padding(16.dp),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
                        ) {
                            Column {
                                Text(text = it.rowItemTitle)
                                Text(text = it.rowItemDesc)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )

                ReusableLazyColumn(
                    lazyColumnItems = columnItems,
                    lazyColumnItemLayout = {
                        Row { Text(text = it.columnItemTitle) }
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyRow(lazyRowItems: Array<T>,
                        lazyRowItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
                        onClickLazyRowItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(300.dp),
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp)
    ) {
        items(lazyRowItems) { itemR ->
            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {
                    onClickLazyRowItem(itemR)
                }) {
                lazyRowItemLayout(itemR)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyColumn(
    lazyColumnItems: Array<T>,
    lazyColumnItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
    onClickLazyColumnItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
    ) {
        items(lazyColumnItems) { itemC -> 
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    onClickLazyColumnItem(itemC)
                }) {
                lazyColumnItemLayout(itemC)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the Column will always show all the items inside it. In order to use two (lazy) columns with the same scrolling direction, you have two options. Either you will add a header to your `ReusableLazyColumn` or you get rid of the `ReusableLazyColumn` altogether and use a `LazyColum` instead of a `Column` with the same children as the code below (`item {...}` for the `ReusableLazyRow` header and `items(columnItems) {...}` for the rest)

```
@Composable
fun <T> ReusableLazyColumn(
    header: @Composable () -> Unit,
    lazyColumnItems: Array<T>,
    lazyColumnItemLayout: @Composable Any.(item: T) -> Unit,
    onClickLazyColumnItem: (T) -> Unit
) {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 0.dp, bottom = 20.dp)
    ) {
        item { header.invoke() }
        items(lazyColumnItems) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clickable {
                    onClickLazyColumnItem(it)
                }) {
                lazyColumnItemLayout(it)
            }
        }
    }
}

--------

Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(contentPadding)
    ) {
        ReusableLazyColumn(
            header = {
                ReusableLazyRow(
                    lazyRowItems = rowItems,
                    lazyRowItemLayout = {
                        Card(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .height(250.dp)
                                .padding(16.dp),
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 16.dp),
                        ) {
                            Column {
                                Text(text = it)
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    onClickLazyRowItem = {}
                )
            },
            lazyColumnItems = columnItems,
            lazyColumnItemLayout = { Row(Modifier.height(120.dp)) { Text(text = it) } },
            onClickLazyColumnItem = {}
        )
}
```